# Using getElementByClassName, and carrying variables through form

Tags: php, javascript, forms, function, getelementsbyclassname

So I'm trying to pass a javascript function value across pages in an html form. I'm using  to show the value, and a hidden input field to store it. Here is my code:

```
  <div class="totalPrice"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="totalPrice" class="totalPrice">
```

It's part of a bigger form, that gets submitted with a button. On the following page:

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['totalPrice'] = $_POST['totalPrice'];
```

On my javascript page, it does the calculations correctly, and here is the javascript function:

```
function getTotal()
{
var weekTotalPrice = weekPrice(); 
document.getElementByClassName('totalPrice').innerHTML = weekTotalPrice;
}
```

Here are the problems:

1. the class function, getElementByClassName, isn't working because I can't see my total price. When I use id just on  with no hidden input field, it works perfectly.
2. My old code in javascript was the following:

   document.getElementByClassName('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Total Price: $" + weekTotalPrice;

However, it still shows the "Total Price: $" part, although clearly I've taken it off. I double checked if I saved my files, and I reset my local MAMP server.

I would love to hear of any solutions to these two problems, much help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName("totalPrice")[0].innerHTML= weekTotalPrice`

Comment: What is your `weekPrice()` function? Are you sure that's working?

Comment: yeah the weekPrice() function is working correctly

Answer (score 4):

Your `getElementByClassName` is wrong, it should be `getElementsByClassName`. Also, `getElementsByClassName` returns a set of items, not a single item. You'll need to specify which item to use. Contrary to this, you can use `getElementById` and specify an ID on the element you wish to change to make it easier to handle. Referencing DOM objects by ID's are faster than classes.

Comment: To select 1st element you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("className")[0]`. But it's better to use `getElementById` ofc.

Comment: Thanks, @Evgeniy +1 for me forgetting to provide example.

Answer (score -1):

Try document.getElementByClassName('totalPrice').innerHTML = " "+weekTotalPrice; and tell me if it printed out correctly.

Comment: `getElementByClassName` is not a valid method.

Comment: You can access an HTML element in different ways:

By using the getElementById() method
By using the getElementsByTagName() method
By using the getElementsByClassName() method

Comment: I think it is valid if only he will DECLARE the class ones. But Switching to ID would be better. I just emphasized HIS method because IT WORKED for him. He just had a problem with the Total Price $ thing. He said his code works so I assumed he only once used the declared class

Comment: and what if HE'LL USE the function again to print results ? He would use, class not Id.